# Dictionary keys in python

Tags: dictionary, python-2.7, count

I am having trouble writing python code to print how many available seats there are in a row. I have a simple set of nested dictionaries - what I need to add is a test to see how many consecutive `keys == available`. the output needs to be something like, 'there is a block of 4 seats available together'.

```
seats = {'A': ['available', 'unavailable','available','available','available'],
         'B': ['unavailable', 'unavailable','available','available','available'],
         'C': ['available', 'unavailable','unavailable','available','available'],
         'D': ['available', 'unavailable','available','unavailable','unavailable']}
```

Is there a very simple method of counting how many items in a row have the same value? I am literally brand new to programming, so I really need explanation of how code is working as well.

Comment: Do you know about list comprehensions? That's how I would do it.
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Does 'in a row' mean consecutive seats or just seats under the same letter?

Comment: consecutive seats within a row. So, 3 seats 'available' in row A, next to each other. for example, seat A3, A4, A5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way -- which may seem over-powered for this problem, but it's a handy tool to learn -- is to use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).  Its job is to group consecutive terms of a sequence together, which is exactly what you want to do here.  For example, if we had a list made of up `1` and `2`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> groupby([1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2])
<itertools.groupby object at 0x8ee793c>
>>> [(key, list(group)) for key, group in groupby([1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2])]
[(1, [1]), (2, [2, 2]), (1, [1]), (2, [2, 2, 2]), (1, [1, 1]), (2, [2])]
```

We can make a list of key-value pairs where the groups are the value.  (Really they're an iterable grouper object, so we have to take the `list` to materialize them to see them.)

So in your case:

```
>>> groupby(seats["A"])
<itertools.groupby object at 0x8ee7e64>
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k,g in groupby(seats["A"])]
[('available', ['available']), ('unavailable', ['unavailable']), ('available', ['available', 'available', 'available'])]
>>> [len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(seats["A"]) if k == 'available']
[1, 3]
>>> max(len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(seats["A"]) if k == 'available')
3
```

With a little more work we could get the locations too, if those were significant.  We can use `enumerate` to give the seats numbers:

```
>>> list(enumerate(seats["A"]))
[(0, 'available'), (1, 'unavailable'), (2, 'available'), (3, 'available'), (4, 'available')]
```

And then group these instead, using the `key` parameter to groupby to tell it we want to group on the second term (index #1), the available/unavailable state, not the number:

```
>>> grouped = groupby(enumerate(seats["A"]), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

and then extract the contiguous available seats:

```
>>> avail = [list(g) for k,g in grouped if k == 'available']
>>> avail
[[(0, 'available')], [(2, 'available'), (3, 'available'), (4, 'available')]]
```

From this we can do all sorts of things.

```
>>> min(avail, key=len) # one of the smallest groups
[(0, 'available')]
>>> max(avail, key=len) # one of the largest groups
[(2, 'available'), (3, 'available'), (4, 'available')]
>>> max(avail, key=len)[0][0] # start of largest
2
>>> next(g for g in avail if len(g) >= 2)
[(2, 'available'), (3, 'available'), (4, 'available')]
```

Comment: Thats so good. thank. I hope i have you ability some ay soon!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty code block that should help get you started:

```
if rowChoice not in seats:  
    # Tell the user they entered a bad row and keep prompting them for input until it works

max_available = 0
available = 0  
for chair in seats[rowChoice]:  
    # When a seat is taken, update the maxium number of available seats and reset our counter  
    if chair != "available":  
        if available > max_available:  
            max_available = available  
        available = 0

    else:
        available += 1  

print "There is a maximum block of %d seats available" % (max_available)
```